# How to use C++ application in a Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, server

My goal is to use a C++ application in a web server written in JavaScript (such as Node.js).
Do you have a solution for combining the two?

Comment: node.js has a [C](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/n-api.html)/[C++](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/addons.html) API. If you want to develop a standalone app, go for child processes as @Hekmatyar answerd.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go too much in depth but in this case spawning process would be the "go to" option I guess.

Something like

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { spawn, exec } = require('child_process');

const logStream = fs.createWriteStream('./logFile.log');
const spawnedProcess = spawn("./some/path/to/executable.exe", [ "-flag1", "-flag2" ]);

// Handle error 
spawnedProcess.stderr.pipe(logStream);

// Read data
spawnedProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
   console.log(data);
});

// Handle on exit
spawnedProcess.on('exit', c => {
    console.log(`Process closed with code: ${c}`);
});

// Send something to the process (the process has to handle it)
spawnedProcess.stdin.write("some command or whatever\n");
```

It will widely differ if it's your cpp app so you can implement handling this kind of communication or not. There's still a possibility to write some C++ "proxy" to let this kind of thing work though.
If that won't work for you then let's hope that in some time someone with better idea will share some solution here.